# Is `JNI_OnLoad` always invoked in main thread?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, java-native-interface

Is `JNI_OnLoad()` always invoked in main thread or in `System.load()`/`System.loadLibrary()` invocation thread? To be more detailed i'm talking about Android (but i think it does not make sense if it's Android or pure Oracle Java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Oracle [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html),

> `jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved);`
>
> > The VM calls JNI_OnLoad when the native library is loaded (for
> >     example, through System.loadLibrary). ...

it is not clear what threading policy should be chosen by implementation. But maybe somewhere it is described in more precise manner.

Anyway, at least on Android `JNI_OnLoad()` is called synchronously, before control returns from `System.load*()`. And it occurs in the same thread where `System.load*()` was called. To ensure you can dig a bit into

- [Runtime.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/41d00b744b7772f9302fdb94dddadb165b951220/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Runtime.java)
- [java_lang_Runtime.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/vm/native/java_lang_Runtime.cpp)
- [Native.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/eclair-release/vm/Native.c)

Also you may try to experiment with it: add logs before and after `System.load*()` and inside `JNI_OnLoad()`, then analyse log order ant thread IDs.

And few thoughts at the end. As per spec `JNI_Onload()` may abort loading:

> If the VM does not recognize the version number returned by JNI_OnLoad, the native library cannot be loaded.

So, if it returns something other than valid `JNI_VERSION_*` constant - `System.load*()` must fail. Consequently, `JNI_ONload()` must return earlier that corresponding `System.load*()`. In multithread environment such behavior may be achieved in two ways:

- run `JNI_ONLoad()` directly inside of `System.load*()`
- proxy it to other thread and block `System.load*()` until it finishes

The second one seems to be overcomplicated and wasteful. So IMO the first one is the only clear choose.